# Running a SQL query via AJAX - where is the mistake?

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I have this script, that has to send inputed data to a processing php page

```
<button id="whatever" onclick="sendData()">Send</button>

        <script>

            function sendData() {
        var header = $('.header_input').val();
        var content = $('.content_input').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'parts/post_functions.php',
            data: {
                header: header,
                content: content
                  }
               });
            }

        </script>
```

And the processing page looks like this:

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "shit", "data");
        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
          echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
          }

      $header = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['header']));
      $content = mysql_real_escape_string(nl2br(htmlentities($_POST['content'])));

      $sql = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO posts (Header, Content) VALUES 
        ('{$header}','{$content}')");
          mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

So how do I receive the data correctly, and of course, send it to a query?

I'm totally new to AJAX, but I believe this is a very simple question for those who have been working with it for a while now.

Comment: I take it you already have a JQuery refrence in your HTML?

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string requires mysql_connect which returns resource. You have mysqli_connect which returns object, then you need to escape your string with mysqli_*

Comment: make sure data is posting to the processing form

Comment: seems your code is correct except whatever @RoyalBg mentioned. then what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
$header = $mysqli->real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['header']));
$content = $mysqli->real_escape_string(nl2br(htmlentities($_POST['content'])));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
<button id="whatever" onclick="sendData()">Send</button>
<script>
    function sendData(){
        var header = jQuery('.header_input').val();
        var content = jQuery('.content_input').val();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'parts/post_functions.php',
            data: {
                header: header,
                content: content
            },
            success: function( data ) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

and

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "shit", "data");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

  $header = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,htmlentities($_POST['header']));
  $content = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,nl2br(htmlentities($_POST['content'])));

  $sql = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO posts (Header, Content) VALUES 
    ('$header','$content')");

  if($sql)
  {
      echo 'done';
  }
  else
  {
      echo 'error';
  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
    <script>

    function sendData() {
    var header = $('.header_input').val();
    var content = $('.content_input').val();
    var dataString = 'header='+header'&content='+content;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'parts/post_functions.php',
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data) {
          alert(data);
        } 
           });
        }

    </script>
```

Now in the PHP page you can access the values by

```
<?php
  $header = $_POST['header'];
  $content = $_POST['content'];
  // ANYTHING THAT YOU `echo` here will be alerted in jquery alert
?>
```

Hope you get some idea